# Suggestion query taking long time

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am using the NEST (c#) client to communicate with Elasticsearch. I am using the suggest API to implement autocomplete in my site, here is my query code sample

```
var completionResult = client.Search(
                body => body
                    .Type("myProject")
                    .Size(5)
                    .Fields("title","tags","control","platform")
                    .SuggestGlobalText(searchText)
                    .SuggestCompletion("SuggestCompletionResult", sfc => sfc
                        .OnField("control.suggestControl"))
                    .SuggestPhrase("SuggestPhraseResult", sfp => sfp
                        .OnField("control.suggestControl"))
                        );
```

i need to get final result as `List<SuggestionList>` and my suggestion list class is

```
 public class SuggestionList
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

the operation i performed to convert the result into `List<SuggestionList>` is

```
    List<SuggestionList> SuggestResultSet = new List<SuggestionList>();     

            if (completionResult != null)
            {
                if (completionResult.Suggest != null && completionResult.Suggest.Count > 0)
                {
                    var suggestionList = completionResult.Suggest.ToList();

                    if (suggestionList != null && suggestionList.Count > 0)
                    {
                        if (suggestionList[0].Value.ToList().Count() != 0 && suggestionList[0].Value.ToList()[0].Options.ToList().Count > 0)
                        {
                            foreach (var text in suggestionList[0].Value.ToList()[0].Options.ToList())
                            {
                                SuggestResultSet.Add(new SuggestionList { Text = text.Text });
                            }
                        }
                        if (suggestionList[1].Value.ToList().Count() != 0 && suggestionList[1].Value.ToList()[0].Options.ToList().Count > 0)
                        {
                            foreach (var text in suggestionList[1].Value.ToList()[0].Options.ToList())
                            {
                                SuggestResultSet.Add(new SuggestionList { Text = text.Text });
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
```

it take longer time to get final result, is there any way to do it without affecting performance

Answer (score 1):

I think you have over complicated your conversion process, nesting is high. Bearing in mind this isn't compiled and is only pseudo.

```
List<SuggestionList> SuggestResultSet = new List<SuggestionList>();
if(completionResults != null)
{
    foreach(var suggestion in completionResults.Suggest)
    {
        SuggestsResultSet.Add(new SuggestionList {Text = suggestion.Text });
    }
}
```